# capture what have been changed inside Dataverse tables and update sharepoint lists accordingly using Power Automate flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform, dataverse

We have 2 data-verse tables named **Invoices** & **Accounts** + 2 SharePoint lists named **Invoices_Logs** & **Accounts_logs**. the dataverse tables will contain the actual values and the SharePoint lists will act as the logs for the updates.

now we are trying to create a power automate flow which will update the SharePoint lists with what have been updated on the Invoices & Accounts dataverse tables (we are updating the dataverse tables using Power Apps canvas app).

So for example; let say a user update the Invoice type field from "Personal" to "Enterprise" + update the Invoice Balance from "10" to "20" and save the changes. so can we capture what has been changed using Power Automate flow and update the SharePoint lists accordingly . so in this case the **Invoices_Logs** SharePoint table will have this value:-

*Invoice Type. old value = Personal / New value = Enterprise. Balance. old value = 10 / new value = 20*

so can we have a Power Automate flow which run when dataverse item got updated and capture the fields that has been modified ? currently i am planning to do this inside the Power App, so i will store the old values inside a variable and when submitting the data i will compare the old values with the new values entered by the user. but this is a length work, so i am trying to do it in a smarter way using Power Automate?

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this Power Automate Template [When a record is updated in Microsoft Dataverse, send an email](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/4da7dbf98cec40e9bcce29c80d305307/when-a-record-is-updated-in-microsoft-dataverse-send-an-email/)

make modifications in the flow to update the SharePoint log lists instead of sending the record changes as email.

Also, you will get more solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70418344/how-to-detect-changes-in-records-of-dataverse-tables)